# how to change webapp url

Tags: tomcat, servlets, web.xml, servletconfig

URL for my webapp which is deployed on tomcat server is:
      `http://host:port/myapp`

How I can change this url to some thing like below for same tomcat home:
`http://test.myapp.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to own the domain from your example URL, or configure local DNS/ hosts entries on your workstation to map URL to your server IP.

Then you will have to bind tomcat to port 80, and deploy your app with name ROOT.war or alternatively use apache http server at front (module mod_proxy might be helpful, check [this link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/proxy-howto.html)).

Comment: Link provided by you regarding proxy is useful and provided me correct track.